# Returning customized results with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get results but couldn't figure out what the query is going to look like. The premise is this, a users has purchased a specific set of items, their gear. When they go to my site, they see kits or setups that users have submitted. I want to only show them setups that have only the gear that they've purchased. They don't need to see setups with gear that they do not have.

Here's what my tables look like:

`[Gear]`

- `gearID` is the unique key
- has a list of all the gear (mics, heads, effects) with unique id's for each

`[Kits]`

- `kitID` is the unique key
- has a list of all the user submitted kits

`[KitGearLink]`

This table connects the `[Kits]` and `[Gear]` with each other. So this is the table that lists out what gear the user submitted kit has.

`[Users]`

- `userID` is the unique key
- list of all the users

`[UserGear]`

Links the [users] and [gear] table together. This is what stores what the user's personal gear consists of.

So how do I pull up records for each user that will show them all the kits that will work with the gear they have? If a kit has something the user doesn't own, then it won't show them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Kit k
WHERE k.KitID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT kg.KitID
    FROM KitGearLink kg
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT ug0.GearID
       FROM UserGear ug0
       WHERE ug0.UserID = @userParam
    ) ug ON kg.GearID = ug.GearID
    WHERE ug.GearID = null
)
```

For a given user id the sub query return kits which fail the gear id join betwen user and kit (kits with a bit of gear the user doesn't have).  This is used to filter the list of kits in the system.

**Edit:** Introduced second sub-query to filter user gear by user id parameter before the left join occurs, see comments.

Comment: Just realised that this will not work because the UserID will be null if the join fails - I will keep on thinking this over!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you want a list of kits where all the gear in the kit has at some point been associated with a specific user.  Best bet is to go through an SP and use a memory table.  This assumes  you are asking for kits for a specific user.  you could get a complete list for all users, but more costly and complex....

```
DECLARE @UserId as int
SELECT @Userid = YOURUSER

Declare @tblUserKits TABLE (
    UserId int null, 
    KitId int null, 
    GearId int null
    )

-- GET ALL KITS THAT A USER HAS AT LEAST ONE PART OF
Insert Into @tbluserkits
    select distinct u.userid, k.kitid, k.gearid
    from usergear u
    inner join Kitgearlink k on u.gearid = k.gearid
    where u.Userid = @UserId

-- DELETE ALL KITS THAT THE USER IS MISSING A PART FOR
Delete from @tblUserKits WHERE KitId in 
    (select distinct t.kitid
    from @tbluserkits t
    inner join kitgearlink k on t.kitid = k.kitid
    left outer join usergear u on k.gearid = u.gearid
    WHERE u.gearid is null)

-- Finally return a list of kits
Select distinct KitId from @tblUserKits
```